# Acces data from objects in a list

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I am trying to convert a a LINQ query result into a list of objects and I seem to be doing something wrong because I can not acces the properties of each object.Here is my code:

```
List<Object> productList = new List<Object>();

        var products = (from p in Products
                       join s in SubCategories on p.SubcatId equals s.SubCatId
                       join b in Brands on p.BrandId equals b.BrandId
                       select new
                                  {
                                      Subcategory = s.SubCatName,
                                      Brand = b.BrandName,
                                      p.ProductName,
                                      p.ProductPrice
                                  }).Where(x => x.Subcategory == subcategory);


        foreach (var product in products)
        {
            productList.Add(product);
        }

        foreach (var produs in productList){
            Console.WriteLine(produs.ProductName);
        }
```

When I try to do this I get an error that says:

```
Object does not contain a definion for ProductName
```

The same goes for all the other fields two

Aldo if I try and do this:

```
Console.WriteLine(produs);
```

I get tables with the data for each field

I have run this for tests on LINQPAD and it also does not work in visual studio.What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
List<Object> productList = new List<Object>();
```

You're declaring it as a `List<object>`, which means when you later write this:

```
foreach (var produs in productList)
```

Then `produs` is implicitly typed as `object`.

The simplest approach would be just to use `ToList()` instead of copying the results to a list yourself:

```
var products = (from p in Products
                join s in SubCategories.Where(x => x.SubCatName == subcategory)
                  on p.SubcatId equals s.SubCatId
                join b in Brands on p.BrandId equals b.BrandId
                select new {
                    Subcategory = s.SubCatName,
                    Brand = b.BrandName,
                    p.ProductName,
                    p.ProductPrice
                }).ToList();
```

Note that I've moved the subcategory name filter as early as possible - there's no need to do it *after* the join. The `ToList()` call at the end will mean the result is a `List<T>` where `T` is your anonymous type.

Then you can use:

```
foreach (var product in products)
{
    Console.WriteLine(produs.ProductName);
}
```

Comment: You are just too quick to the draw friend! Great job!

Comment: This worked perfectly but it seems that my method can not have a return type of List<objects> what type should my return type be?

Comment: @NistorAlexandru: Well we don't know what you're trying to achieve, or what your context is. You could create a named type with the right properties... or do something else. It's hard to give advice without more information.

Comment: I need to be able to return the data I retrieve from the db in a list of objeacts where each object contains Subcategoru , Brand , ProductName , ProductPrice

Comment: @NistorAlexandru: Then you'll need to declare such a class yourself, so that you can return a list of that type.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
List<Product> productList = new List<Product>();
```

instead of

```
List<Object> productList = new List<Object>();
```

where Product is the unit of Products

Comment: I'm going to request you remove this answer because the answer provided by @JonSkeet is the same and more complete. Thanks!

Comment: If it wasn't Jon Skeet I would have made the same request.

Answer (score 0):

A `List` of `Object` means that you only get the methods contained within an `object`. You should do something like:

```
List<Product> productList = new List<Product>();
```

Just as a note you can also do:

```
productList = products.ToList<Product>();
```

instead of iterating over the list and adding each element. (Linq does this for you implicitely).

NOTE: This is assuming that you change your query select to `select new Product { ... }`
This will then allow you to use `List<Product>` productList so that you can pass your Product list to other methods etc.

Comment: I'm going to request you remove this answer because the answer provided by @JonSkeet is the same and more complete. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Request denied? This answers the question completely, as does JonSkeets, I don't see the need for either to be removed.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud You may note, that *unlike* the other answer I suggest *explicitly* type casting the list to a `List<Product>` **not** implicitly by using `var`. I certainly did not update my answer to copy his, in fact I changed it specifically to give the OP a different idea from what was already stated. I have no desire to "compete" against anyone, but if I have already typed up an answer to a question which *completely resolves* the OPs issue, *and* provides *additional* information that the OP might find useful, I see no reason to remove it because someone answered slightly faster.